# How to reuse an ArrayList object without its value being changed in places where its already stored?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, hashset

I have ArrayLists inside an HashSet. I add the numbers into the ArrayList using the for loop and add this ArrayList into the HashSet. But when I manipulate the ArrayList again, the manipulation reflects in the HashSet as well. How can I avoid this? This might be because the reference to the ArrayList object is being stored in the HashSet instead of its value.. This problem might be solved if I create a new ArrayList object each time, but I am trying to avoid that.. Here is the snippet of the code that I wrote to test it..

```
int n=10;
   Set<ArrayList> hash_Set = new HashSet<ArrayList>();
   ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
       al.add(i);
   hash_Set.add(al);
   al.clear();
```

Is there a way around to use the same HashSet object and iteratively add different values each time?? Thanks in advance..

Comment: you have to create a new ArrayList object each time

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do that as far as I know

Comment: I added the 3rd line inside the for loop and each time a new ArrayList object with the name al got created and the older ArrayList object was setup for garbage collection..